# Which SQL Developer Version will be compatible with Oracle 9i

Tags: oracle, oracle-sql-developer, oracle-9i

My Company is using Oracle 9i. I want to connect to the database. I'm planning to use SQL Developer. Which version will be compatible Oracle 9i?

Answer (score 2):

Since SQLDeveloper is a Java program using a jdbc driver, the restrictions are made by the version of the jdbc driver. The v10 and v11 drivers can connect to v9 without any problems. For older version databases you might need to get the v8 or v9 jdbc drivers.

Answer (score 1):

If by 'compatible' you mean 'certified by Oracle', I think you'll need to go back [to SQL Developer 1.5](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/hol08/sqldev_mngdb/sqldev15nf/sqldev_nf_otn.htm):

> Developed in Java, Oracle SQL Developer runs on Windows, Linux and the Mac OS X. With the default connectivity to the database is through the JDBC Thin driver, no Oracle Home is required. To install Oracle SQL Developer simply unzip the downloaded file. This tutorial uses Oracle Database 11g R1. ***You can use any of the Oracle Databases 9.2.0.1 and later***, and any Oracle database edition including the Express Edition.

The earliest [compatibility list on the Internet Archive is for 2.1](https://web.archive.org/web/20100814204142/http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/certification-096745.html), and that is certified back to 10g only:

> Oracle Database Certification
>
> - Oracle Database 11g Release 2
> - Oracle Database 11g Release 1
> - Oracle Database 10g
> - Oracle Database Express Edition 10g
> - Oracle TimesTen In-Memory Database 11g and 7.0
> - Oracle In-Memory Database Cache 11g and 7.0

Answer (score 1):

In practice I managed to work with Oracle 9i using following configuration:

```
SQL Developer 4.0.2.15
Java 1.7
Oracle JDBC driver ojdbc6.jar 11.2.0.3.0.
```

On the latest SQL Developer (17.4.0.355) I managed to connect to 9i and execute sql queries but I got errors when tried to view stored procedures.

Answer (score 0):

There is no restriction in the oracle version.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html

All you need is to connect the application correctly to your oracle instance.

Once you have downloaded the application, you should lauch the sqldeveloper.exe from the downloaded folder.

Once application is launched, you click on view > connections , and then add the oracle instance connection to the application. If you have trouble creating the connection with your database instance, let me know.

Comment: Connecting to older DBs triggers "ORA-01460 unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested"

Comment: @rtaft This is because of newer versions of JDBC drivers that come with more recent versions. But you can use older JDBC Drivers like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/66656752/2761418

Answer (score 0):

The last version I made run with Oracle 9i was 20.2.0.

By following this procedure:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66656752/2761418